# How to remove spaces from a text input box

Tags: jquery, onchange, str-replace

I have the following jQuery shell which works:

```
  $('.jq_noSpaces').on('change', function(){
    alert('you changed the value in the box');
  });
```

My form attributes are `id="username" name="username"`

How do I use the following jQuery replace function to automatically change remove the spaces from the input field?

```
str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the syntax:

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s+/g, ''));
```

Inside the event handler.

Comment: Cool @TomWalters, I'll give it a try now.

Comment: @Diodeus Yep I just spotted that!

Comment: it's missing a right paren somewhere -- I think (or so Dreamweaver is yelling at me about it)

Comment: SIMPLY Awesome !! Thanks @TomWalters -- that's what I needed (gotta wait 9 mins to accept your answer)

Answer (score 4):

Replace content of your box in event handler

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

Answer (score 3):

No need for jQuery at all...just do `this.value = this.value.replace(/s+/g, '');`

Comment: That'll only replace the first space found, you have to add the global flag: `/ /g`

Comment: @TomWalters: Good call. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.jq_noSpaces').on('change', function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s+/g,"")) //thanks @Sushil for the reminder to use the global flag
    alert('you changed the value in the box');
});
```

or, like the others said, you don't really need jQuery at all. I tend to use it anyway, though. All the really cool coders do.